# Angular Showing: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'State')

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to learn routing by adding routing to a specific page in my healthcare app using angular. When I am trying to fetch data this is error what we are getting:

```
users.component.ts:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'State')
    at Object.next (users.component.ts:17:40)
    at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at map.js:7:24
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at filter.js:6:128
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
```

I am writing this code for fetching the value of "data" from [Data response getting from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pDYy.png)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    //Fetch Users
    this.userService.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (successResponse)=>{
        console.log(successResponse[0].State);
      },
    (errorResponse)=>{
      console.log(errorResponse);
    }

    )

  }
```

This code is giving the output
`users.component.ts:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'State')`
Please help me with this as why the data is not fetching properly?
Why is

```
successResponse[0].State
```

not giving the correct output?

Comment: Add/Show the userService in the post.

Comment: I dont see successResponse in your api response. Please show the full response

Answer (score 0):

According to your ScreenShot, it does not contain a key called State. So if you want to access all the data retrieved, the code should be changed as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    //Fetch Users
    this.userService.getAllUsers()
    .subscribe(
      (successResponse)=>{
        console.log(successResponse.data);
      },
    (errorResponse)=>{
      console.log(errorResponse);
    }

    )

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

make it like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
//Fetch Users
this.userService.getAllUsers()
.subscribe(
  (successResponse)=>{
    console.log(successResponse.data[0].State);
  },
(errorResponse)=>{
  console.log(errorResponse);
}

)
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).